# How do I "use" a Perl module in a directory not in @INC?

Tags: perl, module, relative-path

I have a module in the parent directory of my script and I would like to 'use' it.

If I do

```
use '../Foo.pm';
```

I get syntax errors.

I tried to do:

```
push @INC, '..';
use EPMS;
```

and .. apparently doesn't show up in @INC

I'm going crazy!  What's wrong here?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`use` takes place at compile-time, so this would work:

```
BEGIN {push @INC, '..'}
use EPMS;
```

But the better solution is to `use lib`, which is a nicer way of writing the above:

```
use lib '..';
use EPMS;
```

In case you are running from a different directory, though, the use of `FindBin` is recommended:

```
use FindBin;                     # locate this script
use lib "$FindBin::RealBin/..";  # use the parent directory
use EPMS;
```

Comment: Usually you want to do an unshift so you're directory is at the front of the list. That way Perl doesn't have to search through all of @INC to find it. :)

Comment: Yeah, that's right, and so the BEGIN{push}=>`use lib` conversion isn't identical, either.  But I wanted to show the minimum usable change from the question to make it work.  Thanks for noticing :)

Comment: There's also PERL5LIB and the -I switch, as Brian mentions.

Comment: On windows I can call successfully using this method : use lib 'D:\webserver\sites\test\testing'; but not using, use lib '\testing'; (or use lib '..\testing'; or use lib '.\testing';). In both cases I am running script from test folder. How do I do relative naming. Is it difference in Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 26):

There are several ways you can modify `@INC`.

- set `PERL5LIB`, as documented in [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)
- use the `-I` switch on the command line, also documented in [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html). You can also apply this automatically with PERL5OPT, but just use PERL5LIB if you are going to do that.
- `use lib` inside your program, although this is fragile since another person on a different machine might have it in a different directory.
- Manually modify `@INC`, making sure you do that at compile time if you want to pull in a module with use. That's too much work though.
- `require` the filename directly. While this is possible, it doesn't allow that filename to load files in the same directory. This would definitely raise eyebrows in a code review.

Answer (score 16):

Personally I prefer to keep my modules (those that I write for myself or for systems I can control) in a certain directory, and also to place them in a subdirectory. As in:

```
/www/modules/MyMods/Foo.pm
/www/modules/MyMods/Bar.pm
```

And then where I use them:

```
use lib qw(/www/modules);
use MyMods::Foo;
use MyMods::Bar;
```

As an aside..  when it comes to pushing, I prefer the fat-arrow comma:

```
push @array => $pushee;
```

But that's just a matter of preference.

Comment: That pushing syntax looks uber-confusing. It's definitely pointing the wrong way. From a mechanical perspective. Is it the same as a comma? The comma is much more ambiguous about direction, and hence better...

Comment: @StevenLu From [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator): *"The `=>` operator is a synonym for the comma except that it causes a word on its left to be interpreted as a string if it begins with a letter or underscore and is composed only of letters, digits and underscores. [...] Otherwise, the `=>` operator behaves exactly as the comma operator or list argument separator, according to context."* `=>` is also known as the "fat comma."

Comment: Too bad the same does not hold for `<=`.

Answer (score 9):

'use lib' is the answer, as @ephemient mentioned earlier.  One other option is to use require/import instead of use.  It means the module wouldn't be loaded at compile time, but instead in runtime.

That will allow you to modify @INC as you tried there, or you could pass require a path to the file instead of the module name.  From 'perldoc -f require':

> If EXPR is a bareword, the require assumes a ".pm" extension and
>   replaces "::" with "/" in the filename for you, to make it easy to
>   load standard modules.  This form of loading of modules does not risk
>   altering your namespace.

Answer (score 3):

You have to have the `push` processed before the `use` is -- and `use` is processed early.  So, you'll need a `BEGIN { push @INC, ".."; }` to have a chance, I believe.

Comment: Usually you want to do an unshift so you're directory is at the front of the list. That way Perl doesn't have to search through all of @INC to find it. :)

Comment: Yeah, that too...I don't normally use relative names because I don't normally run scripts from a fixed directory, so...

Answer (score 3):

As reported by "perldoc -f use":

> It is exactly equivalent to
>   `BEGIN { require Module; import Module LIST; }`
>   except that Module must be a bareword.

Putting that another way, "use" is equivalent to:

- running at compile time,
- converting the package name to a file name,
- `require`-ing that file name, and
- `import`-ing that package.

So, instead of calling use, you can call require and import inside a BEGIN block:

```
BEGIN {
  require '../EPMS.pm';
  EPMS->import();
}
```

And of course, if your module don't actually do any symbol exporting or other initialization when you call import, you can leave that line out:

```
BEGIN {
  require '../EPMS.pm';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some IDEs don't work correctly with 'use lib', the favored answer.  I found 'use lib::relative' works with my IDE, JetBrains' WebStorm.

see [POD for lib::relative](https://metacpan.org/pod/lib::relative)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is because what you're adding to `@INC` is relative to the current working directory in the command line rather than the script's directory.

For example, if you're currently in:

```
a/b/
```

And the script you're running has this URL:

```
a/b/modules/tests/test1.pl
```

---

```
BEGIN {
    unshift(@INC, "..");    
}
```

The above will mean that `..` results in directory `a/` rather than `a/b/modules`.

Either you must change `..` to `./modules` in your code or do a `cd modules/tests` in the command line before running the script again.