# Bugzilla 5.0 install on OpenShift - Can't locate parent.pm in @INC

Tags: perl, openshift, bugzilla

Attempting to install Bugzilla on an OpenShift small gear. Using SSH to `wget` 5.0 tarball, untar-ing and running the `checksetup.pl --check-modules` script gives me this error:

```
Can't locate parent.pm in @INC (INC contains: . lib /var/openshift/[app-id]/app-root
/runtime/repo/libs /var/lib/openshift/[app-id]/perl/perl5lib/lib/perl5 /usr/local/lib64
/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib/lib64/perl5/vendor-perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor-perl
/usr/lib64/perl5 usr/share/perl5) at Bugzilla/Constants.pm line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Constants.pm line 14.
Compilation failed in require at ./checksetup.pl line 27.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./checksetup.pl line 27.

Line 14 of Bugzilla/Constants.pm: `use parent qw(Exporter);`

Line 27 of ./checksetup.pl: `use Bugzilla::Constants;`
```

`[app-id]` in the paths is just a random string of hex digits used to identify an OpenShift application.

All help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparantly OpenShift has a cpan.txt file in the .openshift folder. Adding `parent` to that folder installed the required module.

Answer (score 1):

That means either `parent` is not installed in your system or it's not a part of @INC.

Try `perldoc -l parent` to see if it's installed or not.

If it's installed then update `PERL5LIB` enviroment variable to add path to directory where module is installed.

If it's not installed then run `cpan parent` to install.

Also see:

- [How do I 'use' a Perl module in a directory not in @INC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185114/how-do-i-use-a-perl-module-in-a-directory-not-in-inc)
- [How to change @INC to find Perl modules in non-standard locations](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be installed there. Running `cpan parent` gives me a Permission denied error, though. Probably OpenShift restricting things.

Comment: It seems you have permission issues. I can't help with that. Maybe try `sudo cpan parent`? BTW I'd suggest using http://perlbrew.pl/

Comment: Apparantly OpenShift has a cpan.txt file in the .openshift folder. Adding `parent` to that folder installed the required module. Thanks for getting me on the right track though :)

Answer (score 0):

**#please install above packages:**

```
[root@rsync ~]# yum install perl-parent -y
```