# How do I import a perl module outside of @INC that does not end in .pm?

Tags: perl, module

## Background

I am attempting to import a perl module that does not end in `.pm` with a method similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/185121/8981474):

```
use lib "/hard/coded/directory"; use scripting;
```

However, when I attempt to import a module in this way, I get the following error when running [`perl -c`](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/PERL/node161.html#SECTION001820000000000000000):

> Can't locate scripting.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ... ... ... /hard/coded/directory) at *name of script* line 47.
>
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at *name of script* line 47.

## Question

How do I import a perl module outside of @INC that does not have `.pm` at the end of the file?

Comment: The module does not end in`.pm`? What is the name of the file with the module code? Why wouldn't you put the code in a file called `the_module.pm`?

Comment: @mob It is a file I don't have privileges to touch.  Yes it had shoddy logic, but it also has a function that I need which is defined inside of it.

Comment: It is a file called `the_module`?

Comment: @mob its called scripting.  I updated it to be less confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file has a `package` directive, the file name and the package directive need to match, so simply fix the file name.

---

If the file doesn't have a `package` directive, you don't have a [module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379109/589924), and you shouldn't use `use` or `require`. This can cause problems.

What you have is sometimes called a library, and you should use [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html).

```
do('/hard/coded/directory/scripting')
   or die $@ || $!;
```

(For proper error checking, the file needs to result in a true value.)

That said, you are probably trying to do something really awful. I'm guessing you're either have a configuration file written in Perl or a poorly written module. Perl is not a suitable choice of language for a configuration file, and avoiding namespaces is just bad programming with no benefit.

Answer (score 2):

If the source file does not define new namespaces or classes and you just want to read the function definitions or data from a file, Perl provides the `do` and `require` functions.

```
do "scripting";
require "scripting";
```

The difference between them is that `require` will look for the file to evaluate to a true value (it expects the last statement in the file to resolve to a non-zero, non-empty value), and will emit a fatal error if this does not happen. (You will often see naked `1;` statements at the end of modules to satisfy this requirement).

If `scripting` really contains class code and you do need all the functionality that the `use` function provides, remember that

```
use Foo::Bar qw(stuff);
```

is just syntactic sugar for

```
BEGIN {
    $file = <find Foo/Bar.pm on @INC>;
    require "$file";
    Foo::Bar->import( qw(stuff) )
}
```

and suggests how you can workaround your inability to use `use`:

```
BEGIN {
    require "scripting";
    scripting->import()
}
```

In theory, the file `scripting` might define some other package and begin with a line like `package Something::Else;`. Then you would load the package in this module with

```
BEGIN {
    require "scripting";
    Something::Else->import();
}
```

Comment: The real difference between `do` and `require` is that **`require` should only be used if the file have a `package` declaration matching the file name** which is obviously not the case here.  Also, both `do` and `require` require the file to result in a true value if you want to be able to perform any kind of error checking.

Comment: Re "*is just syntactic sugar for*", That's not true. It's literally sugar for `BEGIN {
    require Foo::Bar; Foo::Bar::->import( qw(stuff) ); }` and it's not quite equivalent to what you posted in a couple of ways.